# OpenSSH server: how to configure keyboard-interactive authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, authentication

How can I configure the OpenSSH server (on Ubuntu) to allow keyboard-interactive but not password authentication?

I know that public-key-authentication is the preferred one, but I want to test a user setup.

Comment: keyboard-interactive but not password authentication? Can you rephrase that?

Comment: @BennyInc try looking at AuthenticationMethod in sshd_config it looks like they are distinct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication=yes
```

in your sshd.conf

Answer (score 8):

You need to configure PAM for use with OPIE or OTPW, depending on your Ubuntu version. Once you have a one-time password system in place and properly configured via the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` module, then you can setup SSH to make use of it.

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

Don't forget to reload SSH after making changes to the configuration file; otherwise, your changes will not take effect.